# Как достать нужную часть текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть вот такие cookies:

> <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session_id=jhkj43h5kj3h45jh34j5h3kj4h5kj34
> for .site.ru/>, <Cookie
> csrf_token=jnkj2h34jhk2j35nk2n5kj3n24kj5n3kj4n5k3j4n5nms for
> .site.site.ru/>]>

Как мне достать отсюда сам csrf_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение:

```
(?<=csrf_token=)(.*)(?= for)
```

Пример использования :

```
import re

result = re.search(r"(?<=csrf_token=)(.*)(?= for)", "<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session_id=jhkj43h5kj3h45jh34j5h3kj4h5kj34 for .site.ru/>, <Cookie csrf_token=jnkj2h34jhk2j35nk2n5kj3n24kj5n3kj4n5k3j4n5nms for .site.site.ru/>]>")

print(result.group(0))
```

Вывод:

```
jnkj2h34jhk2j35nk2n5kj3n24kj5n3kj4n5k3j4n5nms
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://auto.ru')
print(response.cookies.get('_csrf_token'))
# 63f47877d476b3cd141b4732ddd7f04e6a24a17f96bd3530
```

Если же `cookies` у вас действительно в текстовом формате:

```
text_1 = '<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session_id=jhkj43h5kj3h45jh34j5h3kj4h5kj34 for .site.ru/>, <Cookie csrf_token=jnkj2h34jhk2j35nk2n5kj3n24kj5n3kj4n5k3j4n5nms for .site.site.ru/>]>'

print(re.sub(r'^.*?csrf_token=(.+?)\s+.*$', r'\1', text_1, flags=re.S))
# jnkj2h34jhk2j35nk2n5kj3n24kj5n3kj4n5k3j4n5nms
```